# White screen of death when including Elastica Bundle

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, elastica

I'm trying to add the Elasticsearch bundle to my symfony2 project, when I add the bundle

```
// app/AppKernel.php

public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = array(
        // ...
        new FOS\ElasticaBundle\FOSElasticaBundle(),
    );
}
```

1st case : I don't touch the config file: Result : White screen of death
I put some configuration

```
fos_elastica:
clients:
    default: { host: localhost, port: 9200 }
indexes:
    website:
        client: default
        types:
            user:
                mappings:
                    coordinates: { boost: 5 }
```

Results : White screen of death! 
Does anyone have any idea about what's going on ?

Comment: Have you looked in `app/logs/dev.log`?

Comment: Yes!prod.log instead nothing mentioned in the logs

Comment: Switch to development mode and you see errors.

Comment: @Cerad: can you please add an answer explaining how it works?

Comment: @n.1 if you don't know how to switch environments , just run the command to clean cache of prod env it will give you the errors !